# ADO.NET - Accessing Each DataView in DataViewManager

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

Looks like a silly question, but I can't find a way to access the DataViews in my DataViewManager.
I can see it in the DataViewManager Visualizer window, so there must be a way.

What am I doing wrong?

```
dvm = New DataViewManager(MyDS)      ''-- MyDS is a strongly typed dataset
dvm.CreateDataView(MyDS.Company)
dvm.CreateDataView(MyDS.Sites)

MsgBox(dvm.DataViewSettings.Count)   ''-- shows 7, even though I added only 2.

For Each view As DataView In dvm     ''-- Error!
    MsgBox(view.Table.TableName)
Next
```

I also observed that irrespective of how many DataViews I create, data the DataViewManager Visualizer shows all DataViews in my dataset. Why?

[image]

Comment: DataViewManager contains the _settings_ for the view and there is one setting for each table present in your DataSet.

Comment: Why exactly do you think that you need a `DataViewManager` in the first place? What problem do you think it solves? In case you're not aware, evert `DataTable` already has a `DataView` associated with it in its `DefaultView` property. Maybe what you should be doing is looping through the `Tables` collection of your `DataSet` and getting the `DefaultView` of each `DataTable`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, the default views have a sort/filter applied which I don't want to disturb. I need a new set of dataviews for my use.

Comment: The `CreateDataView` method you're calling is a function and returns the `DataView` object that was created. You can add them to your own collection. Of course, you can also just use the `DataView` constructor. Again, what problem do you think the `DataViewManager` is solving?

Comment: @jm, It doesn't solve anything. I was just trying to go by documentation which suggests that when dealing with multiple dataviews, the dataviewmanager should be the ideal choice. My original purpose was to apply `RowFilter` on child table while my gridview is bound to parent and get my parent dataview filtered. I can't figure out a use of DataViewManager if it doesn't keep a collection of DataViews created by it.

Comment: ...but then if it doesn't keep a collection of DataViews, how is the DataViewManager Visualizer able to get and display the DataViews?

Comment: *My original purpose was to apply RowFilter on child table while my gridview is bound to parent and get my parent dataview filtered* - are you aware that in a dataset with configured datarelations, you can bind a control to your parent table via a bindingsource, and then you can bind a child control to the datarelation on the parent bindingsource? The child bindingsource list then only returns items that are children of the parent bindingsource's Current item

Comment: @CaiusJard, yes, but how do I hide those rows in parent whose child data view returns 0 rows after applying `RowFilter` on child?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I hide those rows in parent whose child data view returns 0 rows after applying RowFilter on child

I've done it like this, but it feels like a nasty hack; I've never read the source deeply enough to know if there is a better way:

- Add a column to your child datatable: `Name: IsShowing, Type: Int, Expression: 1, ReadOnly: True`
- Put the following code:

```
        ChildBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
        ParentBindingSource.RemoveFilter()

        YourDataSet.ChildDataTable.IsShowingColumn.Expression = ""
        YourDataSet.ChildDataTable.Expression = $"IIF([SomeColumn] Like '{SomeFilterText}',1,0)"

        ChildBindingSource.Filter = "[IsShowing] > 0"
        ParentBindingSource.Filter = "Sum(Child.IsShowing) > 0"
```

The removal and re-add triggers a re-evaluation of the expression and the filters. There is probably a way to do this without removing/re-adding but I haven't yet found it.. Expressions are normally only re-evaluated when row data changes; changing an expression doesn't seem to recalculate all the row values/trigger a refresh of the relations and BS filters

It would be great if the parent filter supported complex expressions like `SUM(IIF(Child.SomeColumn = 'SomeFilter',1,0)>0` but the SUM operator expects only a column name in the parent or child. As such, the circuitous route of having a column with an Expression be the part inside the SUM is the only way i've found to leverage the built in filtering

Remember when you test that the search is case sensitive. If you want it not to be you might have to have another column of data that is the lowercase version of what you want to search and lowercase your query string